# Spring Async and timeshares

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create an architecture using Java Spring which will have several background processes which will be running concurrently, listening and pulling information as it arrives from different ZMQ sockets.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. Right now, i'm using the @Async annotation with a TaskPoolExecutor, but the @Async function seems to be blocking the next function call in the stack.

So my questions are
1) Will an @Async function block the next function call in the stack? Or will it fire off that function in a new thread, and continue executing the functions in the current thread.
2) Is there any way to give each Thread an equal timeslice of computing power.
3) Are there any better ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. @Async will run the annotated method asynchronously using the
   specified executor.
2. There is no way to control OS resources
   dedicated to threads.
3. Java has a very convenient
   `CompletableFuture` API for asynchronous computations.  I've
   recently wrote a blog post about the problems with `@Async` and how
   they can be solved with `CompletableFuture`: [Demystifying the Magic
   of Spring: @Async](https://ilyazinkovich.github.io/2018/10/26/demystifying-spring-magic-async.html) .

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. But not sure what the exceptions are that your blogpost covers. seems ok to say the method gets executed on a separate thread, and the caller's thread continues executing.

Comment: @NathanHughes, double-checked, there is no exception, edited the answer. Thanks :)